# Problems getting Vim's omnicppcomplete to work right

Tags: vim, omnicomplete, autocomplete, omnicppcomplete

I'm trying to get OmniCppcomplete to work and I'm running into trouble. I've followed the steps on [this page](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/VimTip1608) (including the things to add to the .vimrc file). I downloaded and extracted the zip file to ~/.vim, I ran the commands it says, I did everything there and it still doesn't work. I also tried downloading the modified stl for the `__STD_NAMESPACE_BEGIN` fix. I ran ctags on the directory and placed the tags file in ~/.vim/tags/cpp.

Whenever I type a class name or namespace name followed by a `.` or `::` or whatever, I only get an error saying `Omni completion (^O^N^P) Pattern not found`. I've run `tselect TestClass` to see that the tags were actually being generated and they are, so I'm at a loss as to what's happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I figured it out. I had been placing my tags in a directory called ~/.vim/tags/cpp/, rather than making a file called cpp and placing it in the tags directory. It seems to work now.